# SFTP timeout issue in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I'm creating SFTP connection in Netsuite. It's showing "Timeout exceeded while establishing SFTP connection". I couldn't set the timeout, because the maximum timeout is 20 seconds.

Can anyone help that How to resolve this timeout issue?

Thanks in advance

```
function sftpConnectionDetails(requestObj){         
var reqstObj=requestObj;

var myHostKey = 'xxx'; 

var passwordGUID = reqstObj.parameters.custpage_username;

var connection = sftp.createConnection({ 

username: 'username: ',

passwordGuid: passwordGUID, 

url: 'yyy.com',

hostKey: myHostKey

});           

var csvFile = file.create({

name:'file.csv' ,

contents: 'csvString',                          

fileType: file.Type.CSV

});                

var uploadedStatus = connection.upload({

directory: '/myhome',

filename: 'file.csv',

file: csvFile,

replaceExisting: false

});

 }
```

Comment: 20 seconds should be plenty of time to connect to an FTP. I'd say there's something wrong with the FTP site if you can't make a connection in 20 seconds. Could you share your code so we can help diagnose better?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have shared my code.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add some instructions to sshd.config file

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
HostbasedAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
Port 22
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```